# Where to put the string in order to shorten my command line (bash) prompt in bash_profile in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

In order to make PS1 shorter than the default one, I type this in the Terminal:

```
PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '
```

but after I changed it, I opened a new Terminal, but it retuerned to the default settings with name@hostname .....etc

so I opened `bash_profile` ,but I get these two lines :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

the question is where should I put `PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization tells about customizing the prompt, including how to set color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in `.bashrc` in your home directory. The file should already exist, you can just add this to the end. Don't use `.bash_profile` for this. `.bash_profile` is loaded by login shells, and the terminal usually does not start login shells.

Comment: thanks a lot man it worked , but could you tell me how to make it colorful , please ?